# Too big itertools.product in Python

Tags: python, python-itertools, cartesian-product

i have a script as following:

```
set=[0,1]
sub=prod(set,repeat=10)
subset = [item for item in sub]
```

In there, subset contains 10 elements of combinations of set.

When i change repeat from 10 to 500, it is impossible to see subset! How can i deal with that problem?

I guess it becomes RAM invader!

Comment: That would be of length `2^500` bytes. Ram of 8GB is `2^30` bytes.

Comment: @UrielEli: `2^500` elements, add a few more bits if you're counting bytes. :-)

Comment: @ShadowRanger right. Basing off `sys.getsizeoff` that would be around `2^511`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not a subset you're making, that's just making a `list` of all the values from the `product`. Asking for all of them at once is equivalent to running a counter from 0 to `2 ** 500`, which, in case it's not clear, would take roughly "heat death of the universe" time even on low-level, close to the metal languages. Written out, you'd have 3273390607896141870013189696827599152216642046043064789483291368096133796404674554883270092325904157150886684127560071009217256545885393053328527589376 different outputs.

You cannot realize all the values, period, let alone all at once. If you want to see some of them, you can iterate the `product` and print as you go:

```
valset = [0, 1]  # Don't name a variable set, it shadows the built-in set

for subset in prod(valset, repeat=10):
    print(subset)  # Be prepared to Ctrl-C this, it will never end on its own
```

or use `itertools.islice` to pull off a manageable number to `list`ify:

```
first10000subsets = list(itertools.islice(prod(valset, repeat=10), 10000))
```

Comment: ShadowRanger thanks. I have to examine all of elements in 2**500. But there is no way to do this quickly and faster.

Comment: @YasinKÜTÜK: No, you don't. If you think you do, it's because you have [an XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/322040), and you've convinced yourself there is no better way to solve it. I *guarantee* you, either there is a better way to solve your problem, *or* your problem cannot be solved, period. The fastest computer in the world cannot *count* one by one to `2**500`, let alone generate that many product `tuple`s. It *cannot* be done. So figure out what your real problem is, and find a better way to solve it.

Comment: What a great answer! I realized you're absolutely right. I just faced an XY prob. what i do not know anything about that. So, i am thinking about the direct solution. I have to find new solutions to my problem in order to deal with that.